# How to find Java API equivalents for Elasticsearch curl + json examples

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using the Java API to interact with Elasticsearch, but am generally finding most of the documentation and examples use raw curl + javascript/json, leaving me at a loss for how to translate this into the Java API equivalent.

So what I'm wondering is whether the Elasticsearch Java Client API offers some way to drop down to "native" json when needed.  Obviously I could create my own HttpClient and execute a curl-style call in Java, but before doing that I wondered if there's already something more elegant built into Elasticsearch?

UPDATE: I finally got fed up with Elasticsearch for this reason and many others.  I switched to Solr and have been very happy -- delivered an awesome finished app on time that's been rock solid and super performant in production!  Solr has a great java client, great docs, super performance, and versatile features, and a totally free GUI monitoring/troubleshooting tool.  I'll be sticking with Solr from now on.

Comment: Doesn't Java API documentation work for you? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html

Comment: @Ashalynd Nope, their Java API documentation didn't answer my question, that's why I came here.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the Java API in question, but in most cases, the answer is loosely yes:

Look for the [`source(String)` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequest.java#L257) on the appropriate `ActionRequest` (or `ActionRequestBuilder`, which generally will call it `setSource`).

For example, if you wanted to send the JSON query associated with a `SearchRequest`, then you could do the following:

```
SearchRequest request =
    Requests.searchRequest("my-index1", "my-index2")
            .types("my-type1", "my-type2")
            .source("{\"query\":{\"match\":{\"user\":\"xyz\"}}}");

SearchResponse response = client.search(request).actionGet();
```

While it is certainly convenient, this is probably best used for debugging rather than production code.

Comment: Thank you for this, I find it absolutely infuriating that the documentation doesn't make it clear there is a way to supply a raw query (including aggregations). If you use the client.prepareSearch() way, it acts like it works, but refuses to return aggregations.

Answer (score 2):

In elasticsearch java api document they provide minimal document.  Go through the test cases in elasticsearch github account. They covered all functionality in elasticsearch as test cases.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/tree/master/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch.

It would be useful

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on Spring Data Elasticsearch:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch
There you could make use of ElasticsearchRepository and therefore build your own custom Repository and make use of @Query annotation.

```
public interface CustomRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<CustomEntity, Long> {
   @Query("{\"match_all\": {}}")
   List<CustomEntity> findAllPersons();
   // prefix Query
   @Query("{\"bool\" : {\"should\" : [{\"prefix\" : {\"lastName\" : \"?0\"}}, {\"prefix\" : {\"firstName\" : \"?0\"}}]}}")
   List<CustomEntity> findByLastNameOrFirstNameStartsWith(String prefix);
}
```